# Get entire BODY content using PHP DOM DOCUMENT

Tags: php

I want to get entire body tag content using DOM Document.

I used following code:

```
$dom = new domDocument;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($html);

/*** the table by its tag name ***/
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

This gives me TExt. I want entire body content.

Comment: You....you don't mean that you're expecting to get things like images and videos as binary objects with `domDocument`, do you?

Comment: do you expecting to get html tags like `<div> <p>`??

Comment: I'm expecting entire raw data inside BODY Tag

Comment: So....let's say we have `<img src="http://whatever.com/img/some_image.jpg"/>` somewhere inside the `body` of our page....you're expecting the image tag as an HTML element as part of the `domDocument` crawl, and **not**, say, the actual jpeg, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the body DOMElement to either [DOMDocument::saveHTML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtml.php) or [DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile()](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php), e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtmlfile('http://stackoverflow.com');

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
if ( $body && 0<$body->length ) {
    $body = $body->item(0);
    echo $doc->savehtml($body);
}
```

prints

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : p in http://stackoverflow.com, line: 2843 [...]
<body class="home-page">
<noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
<div id="notify-container"></div>
<div id="overlay-header"></div>
<div id="custom-header"></div>
<div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="portalLink">
[...]
```

Comment: you still get the "outer" <body></body> tags though. You need to remove them with regex, or see here for another solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254896/4360302

Answer (score 5):

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// ... change, replace ...
// ... mock, traverse ..

$body = $dom->documentElement->lastChild;
$dom->saveHTML($body);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is safer to use PHP tidy extension which can fix invalid XHTML structures and also extract body only:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$htmlBody = $tidy->repairString($html, array(
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'show-body-only' => true,
), 'utf8');
```

Then load extracted body into DOMDocument:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($htmlBody);
```